# Azure AD group based login and MS graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Angular 4 SPA, Web API(.net core 2.0) and Azure AD

**My requirements are:**

1.Restrict authentication(login) to SPA to only certain azure AD Groups. E.g. I have two groups "Sales" and "Marketing" and if user is member of either of the 2 groups then only user should be able to login

2.Once user is logged in, he is allowed to do certain administrative operations on other users using Microsoft Graph API

**My approach**

- To implement requirement #1 I am thinking to implement Identity server which would talk to Azure AD. SPA will then use implicit flow for authentication using identity server as IP
- In order to achieve requirement #2 I think I need to use Oauth 2.0 Authorization code flow or OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant and my web api(.net core 2.0) would act as confidential client which would have it's own access token to perform administrative operations using MS graph API
- So once user is logged in flow would be SPA(having access token to authorize in web api) => Web API(having another access token with high privileges) => MS graph API => Azure AD

**Question**

- Am I on correct path of implementation?
- If not could you please guide me in correct direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is how I solved it**

I used Azure AD V2.0 endpoint, Angular and .net core 2.0

1. Obtain ID and access token from Azure AD using [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit) flow. At this point I don't have user's group information
2. Create web api [secured](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2) by Azure AD. It also recognize access token obtained from step 1
3. Pass access token to API and retrieve group information to decide user could get in SPA
4. Implemented [claims transformation](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/21/managing-azure-ad-group-claims-in-asp-net-core.aspx) and cached it in Web API
5. Created [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.0) in web API to ensure only members of certain groups are allowed to access API end points
6. Web API is set up to communicate with Graph API using client credentials grant flow

Comment: This needs a blog post!

Comment: @ChrisEdgington I would love to write the blog post if you found this helpful!

Comment: I did find this helpful, however still struggling with step 4. How did you implement the claims transformation? An example or any other info you could provide would be really helpful. There's very little information out there on this.

Comment: @ChrisEdgington All you have to do is implement IClaimsTransformation interface. Here is an example: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/21/managing-azure-ad-group-claims-in-asp-net-core.aspx. See heading: Removing Group Claims with Claims Transformation

Comment: Ok so I get that bit. But how did you get the groups into the claim? Like you said if you use the implicit flow with Angular you don't get the group claims in the token. I can make the call to the graph API but obviously doing that on every request isn't good.I think the bit I'm missing is joining up the Graph API call with the Claims Principal.

Comment: Yes, you have to make the call to Graph API and then cache the groups in-memory. So, you won't hit Graph API on every call.

Comment: Thanks @shobhitvaish just about there now. Final question - did you make you Graph API call in the Claims Transformation service and add the add the additional claims there? Or was the API call done somewhere else?

Comment: @ChrisEdgington I created separate graph API service and called it from Claims transformation service. It doesn't matter anyway - you can structure it as you like.